# Passing a number in Terraform Variables to Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Curious as to how I can pass a number to a jinja2 template file in a Terraform -> Ansible flow?

In my tfvars json, I have:

```
{
   "Users": 100
}
```

And in my main.tf, I am calling an ansible playbook upon starting my ec2 instance and running:

```
  - sudo ansible-playbook /PostServerConfiguration.yml --extra-vars '${jsonencode({"lic_users"=var.Users})}'
```

That variable in ansible should go to a jinja2 template file, but I need it as an int and not a string. Would anyone happen to know the solution to pass an int through? In my variables.tf I have also put the type for Users to be a number

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :)

First I tested by running the debug task in the ansible-playbook to output lic_users during runtime. It was 100 as an int, so that crosses off Terraform as the culprit.

I ended up using "{{ lic_users | int }}" in my j2 template and it worked. Thanks all!